# Writing an expression in Qlik Sense: unique value with latest date?

Tags: aggregate-functions, qliksense, qlik-expression

I need some help to create an expression that gives a graph for the number of IDs in one day without repetition. As you can see in the image, one ID may have more than one entry with a different date. How can I select the ID with the latest date only?

[image]

Additionally, it is possible for some entries not having a date so how can I exclude those entries?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Put ID as dimension and measure =  max(Actual Date). Next if( len(trim(Actual Date))='-', null(), Actual Date ) as Actual Date, if( len(trim(Expected Date))='-', null(), Expected Date ) as Expected Date and checkbox omit rows where field is null.